# iOS- Attaching camera picked image to E-mail weird behaviour

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I created a sample app to test how to send camera picked image as an attachment to an email.
In that I have 2buttons. One(*Camera button*) which opens the camera & another button(*Email Button*) that opens the `MFMailComposeViewController`

**imageAttachment is declared in .h file as UIImage type**

```
#pragma mark - Picker Controller delegate
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    imageAttachment = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

//    [self performSelector:@selector(dismissCamera) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];

    [self performSelector:@selector(emailImage) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [picker release];
}
```

In the above method I faced problem. If I uncomment the line

```
//    [self performSelector:@selector(dismissCamera) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
```

& comment the below lines

```
[self performSelector:@selector(emailImage:) withObject:image afterDelay:1.0];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and later I touch the *Email button* then it crashes.
This is weird.. why it crashes? It crashes without any error.?

These are other methods

```
- (void)emailImage
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"first@example.com"];
    [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];

    [picker setSubject:@"Photo"];

    NSString *emailBody = @"Photo clicked ;
    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

    // Create NSData object as PNG image data from camera image
    NSData *myData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageAttachment);

    // Attach image data to the email
    // 'CameraImage.png' is the file name that will be attached to the email
    [picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"CameraImage.png"];

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
```

The below is the code which crashes the app.

```
- (void)dismissCamera
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)btnEmailTouched:(id)sender
{    
    Class mailClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController"));
    if (mailClass != nil)
    {
        // We must always check whether the current device is configured for sending emails
        if ([mailClass canSendMail])
            [self displayComposerSheet];
        else
            [self launchMailAppOnDevice];
    }
    else
        [self launchMailAppOnDevice];
}

#pragma mark Compose Mail
// Displays an email composition interface inside the application. Populates all the Mail fields.
-(void)displayComposerSheet
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [picker setSubject:@"Photo"];

    [picker setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"emailaddress1@domainName.com", nil]];

    NSString *emailBody = @"Photo clicked;
    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

    // Create NSData object as PNG image data from camera image
    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageAttachment);

    // Attach image data to the email
    // 'CameraImage.png' is the file name that will be attached to the email
    [picker addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"CameraImage.png"];

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

    [picker release];
}
```

PS: Both the methods, `- (void)emailImage` & `-(void)displayComposerSheet` uses the same code of lines. I am attaching the same **imageAttachemnt** object as an email attachment, but it is failing when I dismiss the camera & the touch the *Email button* to open `MFMailComposeViewController`

Comment: you can check below example it is fully customized

https://github.com/zhanleewo/ZLMailComposerViewController

There is camera button to attach photo also and much more also attachment list available

Answer (score 0):

Why are you releasing the picker in method

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

Comment: I ran the same code without releasing the picker instance. No Success :(

Comment: It just crashes without error. When I put the break point then I found that it fails to convert the image to data.

Comment: Your UIImage instance didn't have the image then, do you have imagepicker editing enabled?

Comment: use this line UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]; imageAttachment = image;

Comment: tried both. kept `allowsEditing = YES`. & `imageattachment = image`. Still No success.. :(

Comment: can you send me your code so I can check it and send it back to you?